# Why function takes only first value from previous function?

Tags: python

```
fin = open('word.txt')

# Taking a list of letters to compare in the future
def words():
    elements = []
    words = input().split()
    for x in words:
        elements.append(x)
    return(elements)
    
# Compare letters from words() if any of them are in words in the text file
def avoids():
    for a in words():
        print(a)
        for line in fin:
            if a in line:
                print(line)

avoids()
```

I can't figure out why avoids() takes only the first value from words(). Doing 'print(a)' I see all my letters from input, but avoids() running only with the first letter from words()

Comment: Unrelated: return is a keyword, not a function. So go `return elements`.

Comment: first of all, why aren't you returning `words` and doing a pointless copy to `elements` instead?

Comment: Once you read the contents of a file, your file handle is at EOF and further attempts to read it won't return anything.  Your code assumes that it will keep resetting to the start of the file once the end is reached.  It won't.  You're better off reading the file contents once, up front, and saving it.

Comment: Also, the entire body of your `words` function can be replaced with `return input().split()`.  The loop that follows is nothing more than a very bad way to copy a list (which you don't need to do in the first place).

Comment: Since you want to compare letters I'm guessing the input is a string you want to split to characters. The way to do it is `words = list(input())` (or just `return list(input())`).

Comment: @TomKarzes, thank you a lot! Content of file saved to a variable, words replaced, it's working now